# Android Retrieve current network info

Tags: android, location

How to retrieve current network info on android phone. I want string which specifies the area or the location in which the user is currently located.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)** which return the location information based on user location using cell tower and Wi-Fi signals.

You will get Location object with user's Latitude and Longitude values in **[onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)**
and also you can get using user's **[lastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use TelephonyManager to get information about mobile network, such as Sim Country Iso by calling getSimCountryIso(). see this link:[TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

you can use ConnectivityManager to get information about current network connectivity. see this link: [ConnectivityManager](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html&ei=bjTPTu3FH4Gl8gO4vdTDDw&usg=AFQjCNGPBKJlDfnFEv8hFfBqF7YWm5yvOg&sig2=2reVGCzoQUipvUeY0ZcfIQ)

Comment: can we get location of the phone..like "NewYork" using any of above two?

Comment: I think no. but both of them provide good information about the network.